# PHP order of logical operators

Tags: php

I'm curious about how PHP handles conditional statements / order of operations with nesting.  If I use the following `if` condition:

```
if(x == (1 || 2))
{
    // do something
}
```

I would expect it to behave the same as

```
if(x == 1 || x == 2)
{
    // do something
}
```

...but it doesn't.  My first example seems like it would be a handy shorthand that makes pretty good sense, but it doesn't do what I expect.  Can anyone shed some light on the issue?  What exactly does PHP do with my first statement?

Comment: `(1 || 2)` evaluates to `true`

Comment: That was one of the thoughts I had...so it just short-circuits and ignores `x ==` and returns `true` every time?

Comment: no it's not ignoring `==`, but it does comparison in brackets first!

Comment: So just so I can be sure I'm understanding this, x is not a boolean variable, but it is `true` because it's non-zero?  So if `x` were 0, then my expression would return `false` instead of `true`?

Comment: yes, exactly `false != true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for this piece of code:

```
if ($x == ( 1 || 2)) 
{
    // do something
}
```

In PHP, any non-zero number is considered true. Disclaimer: This fact isn't necessarily true in other languages. So in PHP, 0 is the only number considered false. So you're asking if `$x == true` in the above piece of code.

Hence, whenever `$x` is any number other than 0 the statement inside the `if` will resolve as `true`. However, when `$x = 0` then that is equivalent to saying `false == true` which of course will resolve as `false`.

This article might help: [PHP: Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I got myself mixed up about a couple basics, but you hit the point about PHP considering all non-zero numbers as `true`, which is something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Just to follow up with this, you should remember that PHP is built ontop of C, so behaviours like this (non-zero numbers being true) tend to be inherited from its C base.

Answer (score 2):

Your shorthand is logically invalid. In almost every case you'll have to write out the full logical cases for all possibilities you want to test for.

I say 'almost' because in PHP you can do something ridiculous like:

```
if( in_array($x, array(1,2)) ) {
  // code!
}
```

Comment: @Elen my brain is now full of 'Stupid PHP Array Tricks' to make simple logic statements needlessly complex.

Comment: +1 for array trick i really like array ... or stupid array :P

Comment: also in_array is faster than or condition http://codepad.viper-7.com/nWD7TP in worst case[ (one || tow || three ) if three]

Answer (score 1):

```
x == (1 || 2) 

evaluates like this:

(1 (if its false) then testing for 2, if not, the expression returns true)

now it will become:

if(x==true)?
```

Another example taken from ([PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)):

> // foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

```
$b = (true  || foo());
```

Comment: The same with `$b = (false && foo());`, but this format is odd. I'd prefer `if(false && foo())` to demonstrate that `foo()` would never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

See here about the precedence of an operator
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

It will behave the same as math (think BEDMAS), with the brackets being executed first. So your example is behaving as:

```
if (x == ( 1 || 2)) {
  //code
}
```

and because 1 and 2 are both non-zero values (thus both true), you get:

```
if (x == true) {
  //code
}
```

Unfortunately to get what you want you'll need:

```
if (x == 1 || x == 2) {
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first if evaluate result of `1||2` and check that it equal to x

In second its like `this or this or this`

however in first  you can see that `var_dump(1 || 2)` returns every time true so

```
 $x = 3;
 var_dump($x == 1 || 2);
 if($x == 1 || 2){
     echo 'inside if';
  }
```

is also [**true**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zRmiVJ) so it will  print `inside if` even $x is 3

so imo second way is way to go

Answer (score 0):

how would it make sense? you are asking the computer to execute the following logical expression:

**if x == (1 || 2)** which is same as **x == (the result of 1 || 2)**

so your expression would be **x == true** since **1 || 2** would return true

**computers do whatever you tell them to do**

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x == (1 || 2))
{
    // do something
}
```

`OR` and `AND` operations come back with `TRUE` or `FALSE`
you statement says - if x equals (true) - as `1 or 2` will always be true
- this just doesn't make sense...